# Mapping within a map in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, array.prototype.map

I'm trying to map each value and font awesome icon to each button.

Data for each value

```
const test = ["440", "756", "28", "249", "345", "397", "301", "507", "648"]
```

Code to map over font awesome icons

```
const icons = [
        { id:0, name: faHeadphonesAlt, label:'Music'},
        { id:1, name: faPhone, label:'Phone'},
        { id:2, name: faHeartbeat, label:'Health'},
        { id:3, name: faShoppingBag, label: 'Shopping'},
        { id:4, name: faShieldAlt, label: 'Security'}
    ]
```

Attempted resolution

```
test.map(a => {
            return (
                <div>
                <button>
                    {
                        icons.map(icon => {
                            return(
                                <FontAwesomeIcon
                                    id={icon.id}
                                    icon={icon.name}
                                />

                            )
                        })
                    }
                    <hr />
                    £{a}
                </button>
                </div>
            )
        }
    )
```

Any ideas on how I can get each icon to show up in each button whilst mapping over the array of values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi  if you want to show one icon for each button ordered by index  see this

https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-driscoll-03s2n

you don't need to map over each icon  ,  also  you have 9 buttons and 5 icons so i make them 9 icons

so your JSX component render should return

```
  return test.map((a, indx) => {
    return (
      <div>
        <button>
          <FontAwesomeIcon id={icons[indx].id} icon={icons[indx].name} />
          <hr />£{a}
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  });
```

Hope that help's

Answer (score 0):

the return needs to come first:

```
return <div>
         {test.map(a => (
            <button>
                {
                    icons.map(icon => {
                        return(
                            <FontAwesomeIcon
                                id={icon.id}
                                icon={icon.name}
                            />

                        )
                    })
                }
                <hr />
                £{a}
            </button>
          )}
        </div>
```